# First API with WSO2 APIM 4.0.0, creation seem fine but HTTP 404 when trying to call API

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I newly installed an instance of WSO2 API Manager 4.0.0 using the Simple Node configuration https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/install-and-setup/setup/single-node/configuring-a-single-node/ on a virtual machine.

I can create my APIs (with internal existing API, or pizzashack sample) in the WSO2 publisher. But when I try to call the API, using the try out menu, I have a simple 'TypeError: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource.'

In the firefox browser console I have a 'CORS Missing Allow Origin' error on an OPTIONS call to the API manager.
For this issue I've applied https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/design/advanced-topics/enabling-cors-for-apis/ but with no success.

Here's my deployment.toml file with the customization I made.

```
[server]
hostname = "apim-p.<redacted dns>.com"
#offset=0
base_path = "${carbon.protocol}://${carbon.host}:${carbon.management.port}"
#discard_empty_caches = false
server_role = "default"

[super_admin]
username = "<redacted username>"
password = "<redacted password>"
create_admin_account = true

[user_store]
type = "database_unique_id"

[database.apim_db]
type = "postgre"
url = "jdbc:postgresql://<redacted IP>:5432/wso2_apim"
username = "wso2"
password = "<redacted password>"
pool_options.maxActive = 10

[database.shared_db]
type = "postgre"
url = "jdbc:postgresql://<redacted IP>:5432/wso2_shared"
username = "wso2"
password = "<redacted password>"
pool_options.maxActive = 50

[keystore.tls]
file_name =  "apim.<redacted dns>.com.jks"
type =  "JKS"
password =  "<redacted password>"
alias =  "apim-p.<redacted dns>"
key_password =  "<redacted password>"

#[keystore.primary]
#file_name =  "wso2carbon.jks"
#type =  "JKS"
#password =  "wso2carbon"
#alias =  "wso2carbon"
#key_password =  "wso2carbon"

#[keystore.internal]
#file_name =  "wso2carbon.jks"
#type =  "JKS"
#password =  "wso2carbon"
#alias =  "wso2carbon"
#key_password =  "wso2carbon"

[[apim.gateway.environment]]
name = "Production"
type = "production"
display_in_api_console = true
description = "This is a hybrid gateway that handles both production and sandbox token traffic."
show_as_token_endpoint_url = true
service_url = "https://apim-p.<redacted dns>.com:${mgt.transport.https.port}/services/"
username= "${admin.username}"
password= "${admin.password}"
ws_endpoint = "ws://apim-p.<redacted dns>.com:9099"
wss_endpoint = "wss://apim-p.<redacted dns>.com:8099"
http_endpoint = "http://apim-p.<redacted dns>.com:${http.nio.port}"
https_endpoint = "https://apim-p.<redacted dns>.com:${https.nio.port}"
websub_event_receiver_http_endpoint = "http://apim-p.<redacted dns>.com:9021"
websub_event_receiver_https_endpoint = "https://apim-p.<redacted dns>.com:8021"

[apim.sync_runtime_artifacts.gateway]
gateway_labels =["Default"]

#[apim.cache.gateway_token]
#enable = true
#expiry_time = "900s"

#[apim.cache.resource]
#enable = true
#expiry_time = "900s"

#[apim.cache.km_token]
#enable = false
#expiry_time = "15m"

#[apim.cache.recent_apis]
#enable = false

#[apim.cache.scopes]
#enable = true

#[apim.cache.publisher_roles]
#enable = true

#[apim.cache.jwt_claim]
#enable = true
#expiry_time = "15m"

#[apim.cache.tags]
#expiry_time = "2m"

[apim.analytics]
enable = false
config_endpoint = "https://apim-p.<redacted dns>.com:8080/auth/v1"
auth_token = ""

#[apim.key_manager]
#service_url = "https://localhost:${mgt.transport.https.port}/services/"
#username = "$ref{super_admin.username}"
#password = "$ref{super_admin.password}"
#pool.init_idle_capacity = 50
#pool.max_idle = 100
#key_validation_handler_type = "default"
#key_validation_handler_type = "custom"
#key_validation_handler_impl = "org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.keymgt.handlers.DefaultKeyValidationHandler"

#[apim.idp]
#server_url = "https://localhost:${mgt.transport.https.port}"
#authorize_endpoint = "https://localhost:${mgt.transport.https.port}/oauth2/authorize"
#oidc_logout_endpoint = "https://localhost:${mgt.transport.https.port}/oidc/logout"
#oidc_check_session_endpoint = "https://localhost:${mgt.transport.https.port}/oidc/checksession"

#[apim.jwt]
#enable = true
#encoding = "base64" # base64,base64url
#generator_impl = "org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.keymgt.token.JWTGenerator"
#claim_dialect = "http://wso2.org/claims"
#convert_dialect = false
#header = "X-JWT-Assertion"
#signing_algorithm = "SHA256withRSA"
#enable_user_claims = true
#claims_extractor_impl = "org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.token.ExtendedDefaultClaimsRetriever"

#[apim.oauth_config]
#enable_outbound_auth_header = false
#auth_header = "Authorization"
#revoke_endpoint = "https://localhost:${https.nio.port}/revoke"
#enable_token_encryption = false
#enable_token_hashing = false

[apim.devportal]
url = "https://apim-p.<redacted dns>.com:${mgt.transport.https.port}/devportal"
#enable_application_sharing = false
#if application_sharing_type, application_sharing_impl both defined priority goes to application_sharing_impl
#application_sharing_type = "default" #changed type, saml, default #todo: check the new config for rest api
#application_sharing_impl = "org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.SAMLGroupIDExtractorImpl"
#display_multiple_versions = false
#display_deprecated_apis = false
enable_comments = false
enable_ratings = false
enable_forum = false
enable_anonymous_mode=false
enable_cross_tenant_subscriptions = false
#default_reserved_username = "apim_reserved_user"

[apim.cors]
allow_origins = "*"
allow_methods = ["GET","PUT","POST","DELETE","PATCH","OPTIONS"]
allow_headers = ["authorization","Access-Control-Allow-Origin","Content-Type","SOAPAction","apikey","Internal-Key"]
allow_credentials = false

#[apim.throttling]
#enable_data_publishing = true
#enable_policy_deploy = true
#enable_blacklist_condition = true
#enable_persistence = true
#throttle_decision_endpoints = ["tcp://localhost:5672","tcp://localhost:5672"]

#[apim.throttling.blacklist_condition]
#start_delay = "5m"
#period = "1h"

#[apim.throttling.jms]
#start_delay = "5m"

#[apim.throttling.event_sync]
#hostName = "0.0.0.0"
#port = 11224

#[apim.throttling.event_management]
#hostName = "0.0.0.0"
#port = 10005

#[[apim.throttling.url_group]]
#traffic_manager_urls = ["tcp://localhost:9611","tcp://localhost:9611"]
#traffic_manager_auth_urls = ["ssl://localhost:9711","ssl://localhost:9711"]
#type = "loadbalance"

#[[apim.throttling.url_group]]
#traffic_manager_urls = ["tcp://localhost:9611","tcp://localhost:9611"]
#traffic_manager_auth_urls = ["ssl://localhost:9711","ssl://localhost:9711"]
#type = "failover"

#[apim.workflow]
#enable = false
#service_url = "https://localhost:9445/bpmn"
#username = "$ref{super_admin.username}"
#password = "$ref{super_admin.password}"
#callback_endpoint = "https://localhost:${mgt.transport.https.port}/api/am/admin/v0.17/workflows/update-workflow-status"
#token_endpoint = "https://localhost:${https.nio.port}/token"
#client_registration_endpoint = "https://localhost:${mgt.transport.https.port}/client-registration/v0.17/register"
#client_registration_username = "$ref{super_admin.username}"
#client_registration_password = "$ref{super_admin.password}"

#data bridge config
#[transport.receiver]
#type = "binary"
#worker_threads = 10
#session_timeout = "30m"
#keystore.file_name = "$ref{keystore.tls.file_name}"
#keystore.password = "$ref{keystore.tls.password}"
#tcp_port = 9611
#ssl_port = 9711
#ssl_receiver_thread_pool_size = 100
#tcp_receiver_thread_pool_size = 100
#ssl_enabled_protocols = ["TLSv1","TLSv1.1","TLSv1.2"]
#ciphers = ["SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5","SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA"]

[apim.notification]
from_address = "apim-p@<redacted dns>.com"
#username = "APIM"
#password = "APIM+123"
hostname = "smtp.<redacted dns>.com"
port = 25
#enable_start_tls = false
enable_authentication = false
signature = "API Manager PROD"

[output_adapter.email]
from_address = "apim-p@<redacted dns>.com"
hostname = "smtp.<redacted dns>.com"
port = 25
signature = "API Manager PROD"
enable_authentication = false

#[apim.token.revocation]
#notifier_impl = "org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.keymgt.events.TokenRevocationNotifierImpl"
#enable_realtime_notifier = true
#realtime_notifier.ttl = 5000
#enable_persistent_notifier = true
#persistent_notifier.hostname = "https://localhost:2379/v2/keys/jti/"
#persistent_notifier.ttl = 5000
#persistent_notifier.username = "root"
#persistent_notifier.password = "root"

[[event_handler]]
name="userPostSelfRegistration"
subscriptions=["POST_ADD_USER"]

[service_provider]
sp_name_regex = "^[\\sa-zA-Z0-9._-]*$"

[database.local]
url = "jdbc:h2:./repository/database/WSO2CARBON_DB;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE"

[[event_listener]]
id = "token_revocation"
type = "org.wso2.carbon.identity.core.handler.AbstractIdentityHandler"
name = "org.wso2.is.notification.ApimOauthEventInterceptor"
order = 1
[event_listener.properties]
notification_endpoint = "https://apim-p.<redacted dns>.com:${mgt.transport.https.port}/internal/data/v1/notify"
username = "${admin.username}"
password = "${admin.password}"
'header.X-WSO2-KEY-MANAGER' = "default"

[identity_mgt.endpoint]
enable_self_signup_endpoint=false
```

I already spent several days looking for answers within stackoverflow, WSO2 official documentations and WSO2 github, but with no success.

Did I missed something somewhere ?

Comment: Did you accept the certificate of the API Manager from your browser? Try the same API call via a curl command (add -k to the curl request) and see whether you are getting the same error. Also, try to invoke the API call URL in the browser and then try it from the devportal try-out console.

Comment: Thanks for the follow-up @SarankiMagenthirarajah , I've already rule out the certificate problem. I have the same result with or without the -k argument of curl. It returns a 404 error.

Comment: Today I tried installing the 3.2.0 version on the same server and using the same database server with the same driver ... and it worked like a charm ... I don't understand (yet) what's wrong with the 4.0.0 configuration ...

Comment: For me this solution worked
https://stackoverflow.com/a/75236417/6874557

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue until this morning.
https://github.com/wso2/api-manager/issues/68

My context is a little bit different, i use a Docker active-active distributed deployment.

I think I played too much with the deployment.toml, because a remove and recreate container fix the problem.

I don't know if it can help but i added that :

```
[apim.sync_runtime_artifacts.gateway]
enable = true
gateway_labels =["Default"]

[apim.sync_runtime_artifacts.publisher]
artifact_saver = "DBSaver"
publish_directly_to_gateway = true
```

Comment: I have same problem in wso2 api manager 4.1.0, But this solution didn't work!