# How to check the API synapse file in api manager 410

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

In previous api-manager version when we create an api, api synapse files were recorded in `Users/bilal/test/api-manager/wso2am-2.6.0/repository/deployment/server/synapse-configs/default/api`. But in 410 only default apis are there and my apis' synapse file is not there. But the api can be called without issue. Same thing for sequences.

I need to check and change the mediation that was applied. Always changing and uploading from the publisher is too much of work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding to what pubudu has mentioned above. From APIM 3.2.0 onwards, we have introduced [inbuilt artifact synchronizer](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/3.2.0/install-and-setup/setup/distributed-deployment/synchronizing-artifacts-in-a-gateway-cluster/) and this will store the API artifacts such as synapse api definition, mediation sequences and endpoints to the database. It will then use events to distribute these artifact across gateways.

Previously, artifacts were saved to the file system and if you had multiple gateway nodes, file based synchronizers such as NFS, rsync had to be used to deploy these artifacts across gateway cluster.

Because of this new architecture, we removed the artifacts being saved to the file system and provided a [gateway rest API](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/reference/product-apis/gateway-apis/gateway-v2/gateway-v2/), that you can use to view the deployed artifacts or redeploy artifacts in each gateway. If your requirement is to verify the deployed artifact, you can use this API.

And from APIM 4.1.0, we have changed the mediation policies feature to the new [API policies framework](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/design/api-policies/overview/).

If your requirement is to change the meditation sequence manually, you still can create a mediation sequence as you have created for APIM 2.6.0 and use the correct naming convention `<API_NAME>:<VERSION>--<Direction>` (eg: `PizzaShackAPI:v1.0.0--In`) and add it to the sequence directory. This will deploy the policy in the gateway and will be engaged when you invoke the API. However since we no longer keep artifacts in the file system, every restart will clear these directories and only keep the whitelisted files. That's where pubudu's above configurations are used for and you need to add your sequences' name to this configuration under sequences.

Please note that never to use these file based artifacts in your production deployment and only use them for testing progress. This is because whenever you add a policy from the publisher and deploy it in the gateway, this mediation policy will be undeployed and that file will deploy. At the server startup, this will create a inconsistent behaviour. so my recommendation is, you can use this apporach during the sequence development phase and once you have satisfied with it, use the correct apporach and add it as an [API policy](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/design/api-policies/create-policy/#creating-an-api-specific-policy).

Comment: I created a file with TESTAPI--.xml and added. but I didn't work. Is this name correct? I tried TESTAPI--In.xml. Same.

Comment: apologies. Fixed the name issue. use the name as similar to `PizzaShackAPI:v1.0.0--In`

Answer (score 0):

In the latest API Manager version, you can't find those files as those are not written into those files. Those data is kept in the memory.

You can add the following config to the deployment.toml to provide files from the file system.

```
[apim.sync_runtime_artifacts.gateway.skip_list]
apis = ["api1.xml","api2.xml"]
endpoints = ["endpoint1.xml"]
sequences = ["post_with_nobody.xml"]
local_entries = ["file.xml"]
```